# How do PM2 commands on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, pm2, heroku-cli

I'm trying to use pm2 on Heroku.

- When I run: `heroku run bash` and do a `pm2 ls` I get an empty list.
- When I run: `heroku ps:exec` I get "There was an error connecting to the dyno!"

So, how can I use pm2 commands on Heroku, e.g. l: `pm2 reload all`, `pm2 list` and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on run console then add your commands
[image]